Laravel 11 - set evenInMaintenanceMode for all Schedules
As said in the title, if I have say 100 schedules in Laravel, is there a way to set evenInMaintenanceMode globally for all schedules?
Schedule::job(new SomeJob('daily'))->daily()->evenInMaintenanceMode();
Schedule::job(new SomeJob('weekly'))->weekly()->evenInMaintenanceMode();
Schedule::job(new SomeJob('14days'))->weekly()->when(function() { return date('W') % 2; })->evenInMaintenanceMode();
Schedule::job(new SomeJob('monthly'))->monthly()->evenInMaintenanceMode();


collect([…shedules])->each(fn($s) => $s-> evenInMaintenanceMode()) - may work
